# Custom ordering that needs to run on database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to do something like this:

```
Place.order('distance_km(?, ?, latitude, longitude)', params[:lat], params[:long])
```

distance_km is a procedure in Postgresql. The `order` method does not accept this custom string.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order doesn't use the `?` syntax like conditions.  Just put the values in with string substitution.  Note you need to use double quotes for this.

```
Place.order("distance_km(#{params[:lat]}, #{params[:long]}, latitude, longitude)")
```

EDIT - to protect against sql injection via params, call to_f on the params:

```
Place.order("distance_km(#{params[:lat].to_f}, #{params[:long].to_f}, latitude, longitude)")
```

xkcd reference:

```
"Robert'); DROP TABLE Students;--".to_f
=> 0.0

"54.1567'); DROP TABLE Students;--".to_f
=> 54.1567
```

Comment: You are the Man Mr Williams! I was using find_by_sql which had solved the problem, but this is a much more elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Cool.  Btw, note that if params[:lat] or params[:long] aren't passed through, and are therefore `nil`, then calling to_f on them will return `0.0`.  I don't know if this is a problem as such, just something to bear in mind.